# initWithContentsOfFile Plist in viewWillAppear memory leak

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, nsmutablearray, plist, initwithcontentsoffile

I am loading in my plist files as below in ViewVillAppear. On first load I don't have a leak however pressing other tabBar buttons/items and returning to this view I get a leak. I have released this NSMutableArray in the dealloc however it still leaks. Little confused as to why.
(The theProducts3 is an NSMutableArray just as an ivar in .h and its not @property or retained)

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewWillAppear:animated];  

NSString *rootPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0]; NSString *plistPath = [rootPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"basket.plist"];
theProducts3 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];

NSLog(@"Number of objects in item array %i", [theProducts3 count]);
}
```

Releasing the NSMutable array here.

```
-(void)dealloc{
[theProducts3 release];
[super dealloc];
}
```

Any pointers most appreciated! Thanks...

Comment: No, don't autorelease it, that will cause intermittent crashes.  As nothing else is retaining the array, it will be deallocated and you will be left with a dangling pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dealloc` is not the inverse of `viewWillAppear:`.  It's the inverse of `alloc`.  The inverse of `viewWillAppear:` is `viewWillDisappear:`.

What is happening is that when your view is appearing, you are allocating memory, then you are going to a different view controller, coming back, your view is appearing again, and you are allocating yet more memory, thus leaking the original memory.

If your array only needs to hang around so long as your views are in memory, then allocate it in `viewDidLoad:` and release it in `viewDidUnload:` and `dealloc`.  Remember to set the instance variable to `nil` after releasing it.

Comment: thanks so much that was it. I have had a little misunderstanding regarding some men management. But I am learning. I just assumed for every alloc you must release the object however this object is retained by the view as you mentioned above is that correct? Can you also briefly describe to me why you need to set objects to nil after you have released them? I have used to fix another leak I had earlier in the day but didn't really understand why setting nil fixed my previous issue mentioned. Thanks again!

Comment: You are best off reading [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/memorymgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-SW1), but in short: when you call a method that includes `new`, `alloc`, `retain`, or `copy`, you have ownership of that object and it's your responsibility to release it.  You are calling `alloc`, so it's your responsibility to release it.

Comment: If you release an object, then you must also set any pointers to it to `nil`, because otherwise you have a pointer to memory that is liable to be overwritten at any time - if you dereference that pointer, it could very well crash your application.  So to be sure that you don't do that, when you release an object, set the pointers you have to it to `nil`.

Comment: There's a lot less to do with ARC, but you're probably going to be equally lost unless you understand this stuff before moving to it.

Comment: Thanks yes I've read so much documentation however somethings take a while to sink in. Thanks for the additional information and it makes sense. I would use ARC but I am building apps for below iOS 5 so this is not possible. I most of the time manage fine with men management however Ive not used viewWIllAppear up until now. Now that I know when I do read it will be more obvious. Thanks for your help!

Comment: ARC works on iOS 4 as well, with the exception of auto-nilling weak references.  You need the iOS 5 SDK, but you can set the deployment target lower.